# Better importation of variables from .txt file

Tags: c++, beginner, io

I am an artist and a total beginner in C++.

I would like to find a better method of importing my variables from a `values.txt` file, which may contain 18 values in one column:

```
63.64474122
5.214728341
0.405110193
0.261556475
-2.00743E-09
2.76001E-10
34.45902482
15.62249852
0.220861685
2.88127E-09
0.445804979
2.76001E-10
82.11020306
14.02709406
0.507487944
2.88127E-09
-2.00743E-09
0.159178722
```

… or it could contain three rows of six tab-separated columns:

```
63.64474122 5.214728341 0.405110193 0.261556475 -2.00743E-09    2.76001E-10
34.45902482 15.62249852 0.220861685 2.88127E-09 0.445804979 2.76001E-10
82.11020306 14.02709406 0.507487944 2.88127E-09 -2.00743E-09    0.159178722
```

I know my code is ugly.  Could somebody help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14159265

//___________________________________________________

/// variables from the *.txt file 

double x_A = 0;
double y_A = 0;
double d_A = 0;
double m_A = 0;
double c_A = 0;
double t_A = 0;
double x_B = 0;
double y_B = 0;
double d_B = 0;
double m_B = 0;
double c_B = 0;
double t_B = 0;
double x_C = 0;
double y_C = 0;
double d_C = 0;
double m_C = 0;
double c_C = 0;
double t_C = 0;

//__________________________________________________

int trash    = 0;   

//___________________________________

int main() {

    ifstream ifs ("values.txt"); ///LOADING
    if (!ifs)
    // process error
    ifs >> trash;
    ifs >> x_A;
    ifs >> y_A;
    ifs >> d_A;
    ifs >> m_A;
    ifs >> c_A;
    ifs >> t_A;
    ifs >> x_B;
    ifs >> y_B;
    ifs >> d_B;
    ifs >> m_B;
    ifs >> c_B;
    ifs >> t_B;
    ifs >> x_C;
    ifs >> y_C;
    ifs >> d_C;
    ifs >> m_C;
    ifs >> c_C;
    ifs >> t_C;

cout << x_A << endl;
cout << y_A << endl;
cout << d_A << endl;
cout << m_A << endl;
cout << c_A << endl;
cout << t_A << endl;
cout << x_B << endl;
cout << y_B << endl;
cout << d_B << endl;
cout << m_B << endl;
cout << c_B << endl;
cout << t_B << endl;
cout << x_C << endl;
cout << y_C << endl;
cout << d_C << endl;
cout << m_C << endl;
cout << c_C << endl;
cout << t_C << endl;

}
```

Comment: As a fly-by comment, it seems like this should possibly be something like a `struct xydmct { double x, y, d, m, c, t; }` with appropriate constructor, `operator>>` and `operator<<` functions. This would cut down on the repetition or allow it to be placed in a container such as a vector. Would you need help figuring out how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Storing the data in 18 independent variables is awkward.  The naming of your variables suggests that each group of six `double`s represents an object, which I've called a `Sexdoublet`.

Throwing all the code into `main()` is poor practice; there should be a function to do the importing.  It should accept an `istream` parameter and return a `vector` of `Sexdoublet`s.

I don't know what you were hoping to accomplish with `if (!ifs) ifs >> trash;` — if the `ifstream` is bad then you shouldn't try reading from it.

Hard-coding the filename is probably a bad idea.  I've used the convention of reading from either a file that is specified on the command line, or from standard input otherwise.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

/* A struct of six doubles */
struct Sexdoublet {
    double x, y, d, m, c, t;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Sexdoublet &r) {
        return in >> r.x >> r.y >> r.d >> r.m >> r.c >> r.t;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Sexdoublet &r) {
        return out << "[ x = " << r.x
                   << ", y = " << r.y
                   << ", d = " << r.d
                   << ", m = " << r.m
                   << ", c = " << r.c
                   << ", t = " << r.t << " ]";
    }
};

std::vector<Sexdoublet> import(std::istream &in) {
    std::vector<Sexdoublet> data;
    Sexdoublet s;
    while (in >> s) {
        data.push_back(s);
    }
    return data;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // If the first command-line argument is not "-", treat it as the filename
    // from which to read the input.  Otherwise, read from STDIN.
    const char *filename = (argc >= 2 && 0 != strcmp("-", argv[1])) ?
                                argv[1] : NULL;
    std::ifstream f;
    std::istream &in = filename ? (f.open(filename), f) : std::cin;
    if (!f) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening " << filename << ": "
                  << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<Sexdoublet> data = import(in);
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const Sexdoublet &s) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```